# Adding a Gmail action to an Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to design a logic app that sends an e-mail to a given address when a service bus message is received:

[image: Logic App]

The problem is that when I try to save, I get the following error:

> Failed to save logic app MyLogicApp. The operation on workflow
> 'MyLogicApp' cannot be completed because it contains connectors to
> applications 'servicebus' which are not compatible with the Gmail
> connector. Please see https://aka.ms/la-gmaildocs for more
> information.

The linked resource does give directions of how to get around this - setting up a client ID and secret for the GMail connector, but I just want to send an e-mail - I don't need it to be GMail. Is there an easier way around this? It seems like Microsoft's own connectors only work for O365 enterprise accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [outlook.com connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/outlook/) to send email. This connector does not require  enterprise accounts:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [Manage email, calendars, and contacts in Outlook.com by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-outlook).